# JavaScript time series data combination

Tags: javascript, algorithm, datetime, ecmascript-6

I've written code that performs a merge of two streams of sorted time series data. The first stream is taken to be the primary and any successive streams are merged into it, using the nearest timestamp match to align data. It can be assumed that there will only ever be one match per primary timestamp.

```
const primary = [[1,0], [2, 5], [3, 10], [4, 0]];
const aux = [[1.3, 10], [3.4, 20], [6.9, 30]];

let j = 0;
const halfPeriod = (primary[1][0] - primary[0][0]) / 2;

aux.map(val => {
    tsAux = val[0];
    while(j < primary.length) {
        if (tsAux < primary[j][0] + halfPeriod) {
            primary[j].push(val[1]);
            return j++;
        } else {
            primary[j].push(null);
            j++;
        }
    }
});
console.log(primary);
```

I can't quite put my finger on it but something about writing it felt sub-optimal (maybe just because I haven't used any ES6/2017/2018 syntax!), so my question is: is my gut feel correct and is there a neater and more robust way to do this? As a bonus, can it be neatly extended to accommodate:

1. any number of auxiliary data streams rather than just one
2. a primary data stream that doesn't have consistent time increments?